# Remove category attribute script not working in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, setup-upgrade

Hi I am trying to remove the category attribute using Uninstall script but it is not working. Here is my code. `Setup\Uninstall.php`

```
 <?php

namespace Company\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{

    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function uninstall(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

        $entityTypeId = 3; 
//        $entityTypeId = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY;

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0) {
            $eavSetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, 'test_input_field');
        }

        $setup->endSetup();

    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are using `php bin/magento module:uninstall` command?

Comment: no I am using upgrade command, Also I need to mention the module name in the command.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this would only be triggered by something like this `magento module:uninstall Magento_SampleMinimal`

Answer (score 0):

> **Replace This Line :-**

**From :-**

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
```

**To :-**

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
```

Comment: Will try this, which command should i use.

Comment: in your script just replace this line